# Finite abelian groups of odd order

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am reading [this](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/238887959_On_Subsets_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups_with_No_3Term_Arithmetic_Progressions) paper. It is about finite abelian groups of odd order. I need to find maximal subset which doesn't contain 3-term arithmetic progression. I don't understand the need of **odd** order. I have seen other papers on this problem which have the same restriction too. I assume that **even** case may be reduced to **odd** case somehow. I don't understand why **odd** order is special.

The article can be downloaded from [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316595900241/1-s2.0-0097316595900241-main.pdf?_tid=3220d436-70c0-11e3-abf0-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1388345832_ac186e0379c36e04cb13450d36ceabad)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the result for odd order abelian groups has been generalized here (Theorem 1 implies the result of Meshulam):
http://www.math.ksu.edu/~cvs/liu_spencer-roth_group.pdf. Reading the proof there, it seems vital that $k$ is odd (which is in the special case the group order). I am not sure how to treat the case of even order. The statement may be even wrong for even order, or the methods of proof just do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think even order abelian groups are not considered, because there exists 3-term nontrivial arithmetic progressions which consists of 2 numbers.

For example in $\mathbb Z_{10}$, set $\{1,6\}$ contains arithmetic progression. $1 + 1 = 2 * 6$.